# Performance measurement of a C program on Raspberry Pi

Tags: c, performance, raspberry-pi, valgrind, measurement

My C program (a simple PolarSSL client) runs on a Raspberry Pi.
I want to measure the RAM usage and CPU timings of this client.
Valgrind doesn't work on the Raspberry Pi. Instead it throws the following exception:

```
==3199== valgrind: Unrecognised instruction at address 0x4843588.
==3199==    at 0x4843588: ??? (in /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcofi_rpi.so)
```

From what I gather, this exception is a well known problem of Valgrind on the Raspberry.

What can I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

As far as performance goes, `oprofile` might help you. It needs some work to set up though (kernel modules).

http://oprofile.sourceforge.net/examples/